# Why breakdown voltage decreases with increasing FWHM of an asperity?

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, dielectric

I am running a simulation for a dielectric breakdown. I am getting breakdown voltage decreases with FWHM, which does not make sense as field enhancement is higher for a small width. Simulations solve Poisson equation with drift-diffusion and Joule heating.
Any one can help with this issue?

Comment: FWHM (which presumably is *full width at half maximum*) of what exactly?

Comment: yes, it is full width at half maximum.